# Proper return for service functions in nodejs web applications to respond to client synchronously

Tags: node.js, promise, node-mysql

I've posted an approximation of my node web application below. The original problem I had is that I want to be able to let the client know on post to `createentity` whether the insert was successful and the id of the inserted entity. However, `connection.query` having a callback rather than running synchronously, I can't use the `entityservice` how I'd expect in another language, ie simply returning the result synchronously. There are several solutions, and I'm curious which is the best/common practice re node.js or if there is another I'm not thinking of.

1. Passing res down to the service, and responding within a callback; seems poor practice
2. Similarly, passing functions to execute after success/failure to the service; also seems poor practice
3. Returning a promise from the service and setting res based on resolution/failure; seems like services shouldn't return promises but I'm new to node
4. Some better method using appropriate features of node.js of which I'm unaware
5. trying to change the service such that it runs synchronously and just returning the result Other questions/answers have made me leery that this is possible or wise
6. structure the application some other way
7. something else?

```js
//app.js 

var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var path = require('path');

var EntityService = require('./entityService.js');

var app = express();
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })

app.post('/createentity', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
  EntityService.createEntity(req.body.name);
  res.status(200).json(null);
});

app.listen(3000);

//entityService.js

var mysql = require('mysql');

EntityService = function(){

  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : CONNECTION_IP,
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'password',
    database : 'entitydb'
  });

  connection.connect();

  this.createEntity = function(name){
    var record = {name: 'name'};
    var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO entity set ?', record, function(error, results, fields ){
      //want to return the results.insertId from the service
    });
  }
}

module.exports = new EntityService();
```

Comment: `EntityService()` should either return a promise (that is resolved when it's async stuff is done) or take a callback as an argument (that is called when it's async stuff is done) and then the caller of EntityService can use that to know when the work is done and when to send the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct approach here is option 3 - have your service return a Promise

```
this.createEntity = name => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const query = connection.query('...', { name }, (err, results) => {
    if (err) return reject(err);

    return resolve(results.map(r => r.insertId));
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on the latest version of Node, I'd go with the asynch/await syntax.

Your service returns a promise,then your calling code can do:

app.post('/createentity', urlencodedParser, async function(req, res){
  const entity = await EntityService.createEntity(req.body.name);
  res.status(200).json(entity);
});